# Firebase Realtime Database not displaying images in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am new at Android and I am making an app that displays the user's uploaded images of clothes. I can upload the pictures perfectly  but for some reason I cannot display the images from firebase realtime database into the `RecyclerView`. I have been searching for a solution for weeks.

Please help me out. Thank you so much for your time.

**TopActivity.java**

```
public class TopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    //Uploading Images to Firebase
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private Uri ImageUri;
    ArrayList ImageList = new ArrayList();
    private int upload_count = 0;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList urlStrings;
    List<String> imagesEncodedList;
    Uri uri,mImageUri;
    String imageEncoded;
    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference,dbreference;
    private ArrayList<Tops> topslist;
    private TopsAdapter topsAdapter;
    private Context mContext;
    StorageReference ImageFolder,Folder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(TopActivity.this,2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        topslist = new ArrayList<>();
        GetDataFromFirebase();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TopActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Images Please Wait");
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void uploadImage(){
        urlStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        progressDialog.show();
         ImageFolder = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Tops");

        for (upload_count = 0; upload_count < mArrayUri.size(); upload_count++) {

            Uri IndividualImage = (Uri) mArrayUri.get(upload_count);
            final StorageReference ImageName = ImageFolder.child("Top_" + IndividualImage.getLastPathSegment());

            ImageName.putFile(IndividualImage).addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            ImageName.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(
                                    new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                            urlStrings.add(String.valueOf(uri));



                                            if (urlStrings.size() == mArrayUri.size()) {
                                                storeLink(urlStrings);
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                            );
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }

    private void storeLink(ArrayList<String> urlStrings) {
        HashMap<String,String > hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <urlStrings.size() ; i++) {
            hashMap.put("Top "+i, urlStrings.get(i));
        }

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TopsFolder");

        databaseReference.push().setValue(hashMap)
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(TopActivity.this, "Successfully Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                ).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(TopActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        ImageList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        try {

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                if (data.getData() != null) {
                     mImageUri = data.getData();

                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    uploadImage();
                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {

                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            uri = item.getUri();
                            mArrayUri.add(uri);

                            // Get the cursor
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            // Move to first row
                            cursor.moveToFirst();

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                            cursor.close();

                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());

                        uploadImage();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

private void GetDataFromFirebase(){

    //Query query=databaseReference.child("TopsFolder/Tops");
    //query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dbreference=databaseReference.child("TopsFolder");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Tops tops=ds.child("TopsFolder").getValue(Tops.class);
                topslist.add(tops);
            }

            topsAdapter= new TopsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),topslist);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(topsAdapter);
            topsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    dbreference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
}
```

**TopsAdapter.java**

```
public class TopsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TopsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private  static  final String Tag="RecyclerView";
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Tops> topslist;

    public TopsAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Tops> topslist) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.topslist = topslist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TopsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.top_rv_item,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(topslist.get(position).getTop())
                .into(holder.ivTopGallery);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return topslist.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView ivTopGallery;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ivTopGallery=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivTopGallery);
    }
}
}
```

**Tops.java**

```
public class Tops {

    //Model Class

   public String top;

    //Constructors
    public Tops(){}

    public Tops(String top) {
        this.top = top;
    }

    public String getTop() {
        return top;
    }

    public void setTop(String top) {
        this.top = top;
    }
}
```

**top_rv_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivTopGallery"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my database structure.

[image]

**Update**
so I changed my code to fit the data structure

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- TopsFolder
         |
         --- pushedId
         |     |
         |     --- top: "https://..."
         |
         --- pushedId
               |
               --- top: "https://..."
```

Here is the change I made in my TopsActivity.java

```
private void storeLink(ArrayList<String> urlStrings) {

        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TopsFolder");
        for (int i = 1; i <urlStrings.size() ; i++) {

           hashMap.put("Top "+i, urlStrings.get(i));
            databaseReference.push().setValue(hashMap);
        }

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(TopActivity.this, "Successfully Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ImageList.clear();
    }
```

put now I am getting this as my data structure. What do I do to get it in the format mentioned above?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot map the objects that exist under the `TopsFolder` node into objects of type `Tops` because none of those objects actually represents an object of type `Tops`. However, if you need to map each object into a `Tops` object, you need to restructure your schema like so:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- TopsFolder
         |
         --- pushedId
         |     |
         |     --- top: "https://..."
         |
         --- pushedId
               |
               --- top: "https://..."
```

In this way, each object under `TopsFolder` represents a `Tops` object. See, the name of the property is "top", as in your `Tops` class, and the "value" is the actual URL. The code required should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String url = ds.getValue(String.class);
            if (topList != null) toplist.clear(); // Clear the list if there's anything already in the list 
            topslist.add(url);
    }
    topsAdapter= new TopsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), topslist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(topsAdapter);
    topsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Edit:**

```
Tops tops = new Tops("https://...");
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference topFolderRef = rootRef.child("TopsFolder");
topFolderRef.push().setValue(tops);
```

Please also don't forget to make the `top` property private in your `Tops` class.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I am sorry but what changes should I make in my TopsActivity.java so that  my images  get stored in the realtime database as per the structure you have shown. Thank you for your time

Comment: Please check my updated answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: Hi, I made some changes, can you please check the update I have made to my question and help me out?Thank you so much

Comment: No, it's still not correct! The keys should always be "top", as the property name in your class and **NOT** `Top 1`, `Top 2`, and so on. A single child should only contain a single `top: "https://..."`, because you only have a single property in your class, ok?

Comment: I am so sorry but can you please tell me what changes to make in the code so as to get the structure you mentioned becuase in the app the user is suppose to select images from the gallery of the phone and the they are  uploaded to firebase. I cannot use theis ````Tops tops = new Tops("https://...");````

Comment: Simply push a single key-value pair under each random node.

Answer (score 1):

Your database actually stores a list of `String` under `TopsFolder` node and you need to get those as a list of strings. Hence I would recommend changing your `onDataChange` implementation inside `GetDataFromFirebase` function as follows.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // You should have the elements as an array of string. 
            Tops[] tops = ds.child("TopsFolder").getValue(Tops[].class);
            if (topList != null) toplist.clear(); // Clear the list if there's anything already in the list 
            topslist = Arrays.asList(tops);  // Assign the items to the list from the array that you retrieved from firebase database.
    }

    topsAdapter= new TopsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), topslist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(topsAdapter);
    topsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Picasso Library `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`
this works for me.

```
public static void setUrlImageInView(Context context, String url, ImageView view) {
    // (optional) use Picasso to download and show to image
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view);

}
```

Another thing to consider is that you are getting data from the same child again. You must use Id of document in your example case

```
Tops tops=ds.child("-MIPf9A2H_.....").getValue(Tops.class);
topslist.add(tops);
```